# Calculate the difference between last 2 records in 1 column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the difference between the last 2 values in a column.
Here is what I am trying to achieve;

```
Select abs(water1-water2)/60
from (select dec_pw_water_reset from timer_table order by desc limit 1 as water1) t1
join
(select dec_pw_water_reset from timer_table order by desc limit 1,1 as water2) t2
```

Comment: "order by desc"?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table your using, it will help.

Comment: @GurV's answer is good, but just a small pointer to help you in the future: Even though rows are technically in a given order in the table, to help you work with the data, you should assume that unless you use an *order by*, rows are unsorted. (Also, the order they are actually stored in could change.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an auto incrementing id column you can use two subqueries in the select:

```
select abs(
    (select dec_pw_water_reset from timer_table order by id desc limit 1) -
    (select dec_pw_water_reset from timer_table order by id desc limit 1, 1)
    ) / 60 as diff;
```

Adjust the order by clause as per your needs.

[Demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/TCUY98802)